# How do I Inform user that an element does not exist in a table?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a get details form, and I know that using try and catch as a way of validation here is bad practice. How would I check to see if the CustID exists and then tell the user that what they entered does not exist?

Apologies if this is a silly question and it's obvious and..., I'm a beginner.

```
public void getdetails()
{
    lblMessage.Text = "";
    if (txtCID.Text == "")
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please enter a Customer ID before obtaining details.";
    }
    else
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.Connection = conn;                
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "GetCustomer";
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@CustID";
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = txtCID.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add(param);
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        txtFName.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("FirstName");
        txtFName.DataBind();
        txtLName.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Surname");
        txtLName.DataBind();
        rdoGender.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Gender").ToString();
        txtAge.DataBind();
        txtAge.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<int>("Age").ToString();
        txtAge.DataBind();
        txtAdd1.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Address1").ToString();
        txtAge.DataBind();
        txtAdd2.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Address2").ToString();
        txtAge.DataBind();
        txtCity.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("City").ToString();
        txtAge.DataBind();
        txtPhone.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Phone").ToString();
        txtAge.DataBind();
        txtMobile.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Mobile").ToString();
        txtAge.DataBind();
        txtEmail.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Email").ToString();
        txtEmail.DataBind();

        command.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understood your question. What I would do is:

```
public bool getdetails()
{
    bool found = false;
    int id;
    bool isnumber;
    lblMessage.Text = "";
    isnumber = int.TryParse(txtCID.Text, out id);
    if (!isnumber)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please enter a valid Customer ID before obtaining details.";
    }
    else
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.Connection = conn;                
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "GetCustomer";
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@CustID";
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = id;

        command.Parameters.Add(param);
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
          txtFName.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("FirstName");
          txtFName.DataBind();
          txtLName.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Surname");
          txtLName.DataBind();
          rdoGender.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Gender").ToString();
          txtAge.DataBind();
          txtAge.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<int>("Age").ToString();
          txtAge.DataBind();
          txtAdd1.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Address1").ToString();
          txtAge.DataBind();
          txtAdd2.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Address2").ToString();
          txtAge.DataBind();
          txtCity.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("City").ToString();
          txtAge.DataBind();
          txtPhone.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Phone").ToString();
          txtAge.DataBind();
          txtMobile.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Mobile").ToString();
          txtAge.DataBind();
          txtEmail.Text = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Email").ToString();
          txtEmail.DataBind();
          found = true;
        }
        else
        {
           lblMessage.Text = "User with ID " + id + " does not exists";
        }
        command.Connection.Close();
    }
    return found;
}
```

The function will return false if either the id is not specified or does not exist. Another problem is that you don't check if txtCID.Text contains a valid number: in this case a SQL error is would thrown! 
I added a number conversion check that ensures that at least the stored procedure execution runs without errors. Anyway, you should wrap the whole procedure in a try-catch to intercept any unpredictable error (db offline or internal db error, etc).
Then, I use table.Rows.Count to verify if the stored procedure returned a result.

Mario.

Answer (score 3):

Since you fill a `DataTable` it's easy to determine if the customer existed, use `DataTable.Rows.Count > 0`:

```
bool customerExists = table.Rows.Count > 0;
if(!customerExists)
{
    lblMessage.Text = $"The customer with CustomerID={txtCID.Text} is unknown.";        
}
```

Apart from that...

- Use the `using`-statement for your connection and everything that implements `IDisposable`
- convert the string to `int` with C#, don't let the database do it for you. On that way, using `int.TryParse`, you also validate the input

So here is your method including these and other improvements:

```
public void LoadCustomerDetails()
{
    lblMessage.Text = "";
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCID.Text))
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please enter a CustomerID before obtaining details.";
        return;
    }

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    int customerID;
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TestDbCon))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetCustomer", conn))
    using (var cmd = da.SelectCommand)
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (!int.TryParse(txtCID.Text.Trim(), out customerID))
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please enter a valid integer CustomerID before obtaining details.";
            return;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customerID;
        da.Fill(table); // you don't need to open/close the connection with Fill
    }

    if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = $"No customer with CustomerID={customerID} found.";
        return;
    }

    DataRow custumerRow = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Single(); // to cause an exception on multiple customers with this ID
    txtFName.Text = custumerRow.Field<string>("FirstName");
    txtLName.Text = custumerRow.Field<string>("Surname");
    rdoGender.Text = custumerRow.Field<string>("Gender").ToString();
    txtAge.Text = custumerRow.Field<int>("Age").ToString();
    txtAdd1.Text = custumerRow.Field<string>("Address1").ToString();
    txtAdd2.Text = custumerRow.Field<string>("Address2").ToString();
    txtCity.Text = custumerRow.Field<string>("City").ToString();
    txtPhone.Text = custumerRow.Field<string>("Phone").ToString();
    txtMobile.Text = custumerRow.Field<string>("Mobile").ToString();
    txtEmail.Text = custumerRow.Field<string>("Email").ToString();
}
```

Comment: Using (command.Connection = conn){ int CID = Convert.ToInt32(txtCID.Text);
                bool customerExists = table.Rows.Count > 0;
                if (!customerExists)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = $"The customer with CustomerID= {CID} is unknown.";
                }

Is that how I would do it?